# how do we create array column in Python by looping over multiple arrays simultaneously in the table

Tags: python

We have a table with array columns ids and scores. Each array has 5 elements. Suppose we want to create new table with column id_wise_scores by looping over multiple arrays simultaneously (by index), how do we do that in Python? Example:

```
| ids                   | scores                               | 
| --------------------- | ------------------------------------ | 
| [0, 1, 22, 56, 204]   | [0.98, 0.56, 0.078, 0.23, 1.45]      | 
| [0, 1, 22, 56, 204]   | [0.68, 0.666, 3.56, 5.6, 0.078]      | 
| [0, 1, 22, 56, 204]   | [0.665, 0.298, 4.66, 0.0004, 0.45]   | 
| [0, 1, 22, 56, 204]   | [5.34, 1.34, 4.34, 0.23, 0.90]       | 
| [0, 1, 22, 56, 204]   | [0.009, 0.45, 1.22, 5.67, 2.23]      | 
| [0, 1, 22, 56, 204]   | [0.56, 0.67, 5.56, 1.64, 0.088]      | 
| [0, 1, 22, 56, 204]   | [0.34, 0.934, 3.42, 3.33, 0.40]      |
```

We want to create id wise scores column.
Expected result:

```
| id   | id_wise_scores                                 | 
| ---- | ---------------------------------------------- | 
| 0    | [0.98, 0.68, 0.665, 5.34, 0.009, 0.56, 0.34]   | 
| 1    | [0.56, 0.666, 0.298, 1.34, 0.45, 0.67, 0.934]  | 
| 22   | [0.078, 3.56, 4.66, 4.34, 1.22, 5.56, 3.42 ]   | 
| 56   | [0.23, 5.6, 0.0004, 0.23, 5.67, 1.64, 3.33]    | 
| 204  | [1.45, 0.078, 0.45, 0.90, 2.23, 0.088, 0.40]   |
```

I tried using zip fiction for the same, but number of rows are huge doesn’t seem like working.

Comment: "We have a table". That's not very helpful. Is it a database table, a CSV, something else? Also, you seem to have forgotten to post your code [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

It can be achievable using **zip** function. Please have a look

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    'ids': [
        [0, 1, 22, 56, 204],
        [0, 1, 22, 56, 204],
        [0, 1, 22, 56, 204],
        [0, 1, 22, 56, 204],
        [0, 1, 22, 56, 204],
        [0, 1, 22, 56, 204],
        [0, 1, 22, 56, 204]
    ],
    'scores': [
        [0.98, 0.56, 0.078, 0.23, 1.45],
        [0.68, 0.666, 3.56, 5.6, 0.078],
        [0.665, 0.298, 4.66, 0.0004, 0.45],
        [5.34, 1.34, 4.34, 0.23, 0.90],
        [0.009, 0.45, 1.22, 5.67, 2.23],
        [0.56, 0.67, 5.56, 1.64, 0.088],
        [0.34, 0.934, 3.42, 3.33, 0.40]
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create id_wise_scores column
df['id_wise_scores'] = [
    [score for _, score in sorted(zip(ids, scores), key=lambda x: x[0])]
    for ids, scores in zip(df['ids'], df['scores'])
]

# Create the result dataframe
result_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': sorted(set(id_ for ids in df['ids'] for id_ in ids)),
    'id_wise_scores': [
        sorted([
            score for ids, scores in zip(df['ids'], df['scores'])
            for id_, score in zip(ids, scores) if id_ == id_val
        ]) for id_val in sorted(set(id_ for ids in df['ids'] for id_ in ids))
    ]
})

print(result_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the groups of IDs are identical you could easily build a dictionary to represent the output you require as follows:

```
ids = [
    [0, 1, 22, 56, 204],
    [0, 1, 22, 56, 204],
    [0, 1, 22, 56, 204],
    [0, 1, 22, 56, 204],
    [0, 1, 22, 56, 204],
    [0, 1, 22, 56, 204],
    [0, 1, 22, 56, 204],
]

scores = [
    [0.98, 0.56, 0.078, 0.23, 1.45],
    [0.68, 0.666, 3.56, 5.6, 0.078],
    [0.665, 0.298, 4.66, 0.0004, 0.45],
    [5.34, 1.34, 4.34, 0.23, 0.90],
    [0.009, 0.45, 1.22, 5.67, 2.23],
    [0.56, 0.67, 5.56, 1.64, 0.088],
    [0.34, 0.934, 3.42, 3.33, 0.40],
]

output = dict()

for a, b in zip(ids, scores):
    for _a, _b in zip(a, b):
        output.setdefault(_a, []).append(_b)

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
{0: [0.98, 0.68, 0.665, 5.34, 0.009, 0.56, 0.34], 1: [0.56, 0.666, 0.298, 1.34, 0.45, 0.67, 0.934], 22: [0.078, 3.56, 4.66, 4.34, 1.22, 5.56, 3.42], 56: [0.23, 5.6, 0.0004, 0.23, 5.67, 1.64, 3.33], 204: [1.45, 0.078, 0.45, 0.9, 2.23, 0.088, 0.4]}
```